# iOS audio control issue in AVAudioPlayer issue

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I am writing a function that once users click the Mute button on the screen, the audio will be muted. As you can see the following code:

```
   @IBAction func muteButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    muteButton.isHidden = true
    unMuteButton.isHidden = false
    audioPlayer.setVolume(0.0, fadeDuration: 5)
    AppSettingManager.share.updateAudioMute(to: true)

}
```

I initialize the `audioPlayer` instance in `AppDelegate` file like this:

```
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
```

However, when I test it, the app crashes.

[image]

I am getting a bit confused, how to resolve this, thanks in advance. :)

Comment: It would seem that `audioPlayer` inside your function is nil

Comment: I initialized the audioPlayer in the AppDelegate file, the reason why I did that coz I need to control the audio in other ViewController as well. :) Do you have any other way to refer the audioPlayer in different ViewControllers?

Comment: Write some `PlayerController` class which holds the AVPlayer and have a shared instance of that class

Comment: Cheers man, let me have a go and see how far I can go